# Get runtime library version programmatically

Tags: c++, microsoft-runtime-library

Is it possible to get the version of the runtime library of a c++ win32 application at runtime? I'm talking about MT vs MTd vs MD vs MDd.

Comment: You could always add your own #define for it when MT etc is set

Comment: @paulm What is the easiest way to go about that?

Comment: The `_DLL` macro is defined if you compile with /MD in effect.  The `_DEBUG` macro distinguishes between the debug and the release version of the CRT.  MSDN page [is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx).